# Error in TYPO3 extension manager after faulty extension installation

Tags: web, typo3, content-management-system

I wanted to install the extension `image_autoresize`. For whatever reason it did not get through. I reloaded the page and since then every time I want to open the extension manager it shows me this:

> (1/1) Error
> Class 'Causal\ImageAutoresize\EventListener\ExtensionManagerEventListener' not found
> in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/typo3_src-10.4.36/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 3524

and like dozens more errors.

I tried to logout and login. Tried to clear all caches.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if there is a subdirectory `image_autoresize` in `typo3conf/ext`. If yes, delete the complete folder.

After that, check the array in `typo3conf/PackageStates.php` if there is an array key with `image_autoresize`. If yes, delete the key and the subkey `packagePath`.

After that you should clear all caches. Best would be to do that via the TYPO3 install tool via `domain.tld/install.php`.